# profiling maven dependencies for different branches

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I work with spring framework (home project) and have two major versions of the same project (branches).

- The first one is a 'pure' spring framework using manually configured package dependencies inside pom.
- The second is for spring boot and because of spring-boot automation (concerning dependencies) it has slightly different dependencies inside pom.

**Question**: Is there a way to have those two different pom's dependencies inside one file (something similar to profiles)? Or is there another better solution to keep this two configurations?

Comment: If you have two branches, then keep the list of dependencies specific to each, and then merge the branch to the trunk once the development has completed. If these are really two separate projects, you might consider defining a common parent maven pom which holds the shared properties and dependencies.

Comment: The point is that these branches should have the same codes. The different is only some java configuration classes in spring boot and dependencies in pom. I want to have these separated branches in case of need one of them. The code in application should be merged to both of  them. I think that I will make a patch from one of this branches.

Comment: You say, something similar to profiles, but why aren't you using profiles for that @kropla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Maven profiles to have separate plugins or dependencies for a specific Maven profile, for example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-2</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In this case, if you use `-P profile-1` while building it will add library-1. With `-P profile-2` it will include library-2 and library-3.

---

While your use case isn't entirely clear to me, it doesn't sound like this is one project at all. I mean, if you have one project it seems weird to me that you're switching Spring boot/non Spring boot.

If you have multiple projects requiring the same classes, you can always create a separate module containing those classes. You can then use:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.common.library")
```

And now your shared classes will be used by both your Spring boot and non-Spring boot project.

---

If you're trying out Spring boot on a specific project or you're converting from vanilla Spring to Spring boot, then you should use a VCS (like Git) to handle that, create a new branch to develop your Spring boot application and merge it into your master branch when it's finished.